# How to get short value using Double Function?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)
>   [Rounding double values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129804/rounding-double-values-in-c-sharp)

my double function generating values like this

```
  56,365989365
```

i want just value like this `56,36` 
how to get this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129804/rounding-double-values-in-c-sharp and many others have good examples of how you can round in the .Net framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Math.Round`. The second argument is the number of places.

```
var x = Math.Round(56.365989365, 2);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to trucate the value:

```
value *= 100;
value = Math.Truncate(value);
value /= 100;
```

If you want to round the value:

```
value = Math.round(value, 2);
```

Comment: +1 from me for spotting the truncate.