# How to ensure a precison on float using entity framework 6.x and a float column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I tried to understand why it seems not to be possible to exactly set a precision for a float / double value.

However .NET allows me to use Math.Round on such values an the inspector Shows me exactly what I rounded and / or entered.

Whenever I try to save such a value back to a table I get a Statement containing 86,609001159668 instead of 86,609

There seems so be now way in which the entered value reaches the table correctly.

I could change anything in my code to achieve this Goal but not the columntype itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding double values in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129804/rounding-double-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: How did you even get that the generated statement contains `86.609001159668`? Isn't the value passed as a DbParameter?

Answer (score 4):

.NET floats aren't decimal-precise. The only BCL decimal type that is decimal-precise is `decimal`. `float` and `double` are binary "decimals", so there's no way to represent `86.609` precisely in them. Using `Math.Round` simply brings the value close enough to `86.609` that it's printed out as such during the rounding happening as part of `ToString`.

So if you want precise decimal-point decimals, use `decimal` in .NET.